# shutting down automatically

Tags: 14.04

help wanted

I am using windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.4 , while  watching videos my Ubuntu is shutting down automatically I am having trouble with face-book videos, yahoo videos but
you-tube is playing fine . Someone help fix it .
                                        jos

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `System Settings > Power`

Change `"Suspend when inactive for"` to `"Don't suspend"`.

Answer (score 0):

Or try installing Caffeine, see: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/stop-ubuntu-sleeping-caffeine

Answer (score 0):

This could also be a hardware problem. First is your graphics card supported by openGL. This is on the manufactures web site. If it's not you need one that is to get the video programs to work correctly. If it is, check for graphics drives in your additional drivers option in the software sources menu.Second the problem could be a temperature rise from the graphics card. When you go to watch the video your graphics card increases in temperature which raises the temperature of the system unit and ultimately the processes which will cause the system to shutdown. Check the temperature by using the Smart check option in your disks application. If you are running over 40 C your hot. If this is the problem make sure you have a nice layer of thermal compound on the processor and add fans, but most important a rear vent below the graphics card. TTFN, the toachGmon

Comment: what is this ? uvcvideo failed to initialize the device -5 how will i fix this error ??